# Solve for these 2 ODE equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve these ODE's? Do I need to find the value of my y variable or do I need to find solutions for the function in the derivative? Would like to know how it is done. Many thanks :). P.S. new to all these higher level mathematics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The first ODE**

Let's write it in a more convenient notation:
$$yy'=0,\,\, y(0)=1$$

What does this ODE says? a function times it's derivative is the constant zero, so at least one of the functions should be the the zero function. One trivial solution is $y=0$ since it satisfies the ODE, but it doesn't satisfy the initial value! So we must have $y'=0$ so $y=c$, from the initial value we conclude the solution is $y=1$.

**The second ODE**

You can solve this ODE using the Laplace transform. let me know in the comments if you don't know how.

---

**SKETCH FOR SOLUTION USING THE LAPLACE TRANSFORM**

We usually solve ODEs by applying the Laplace transform for linear differential equations (not necessarily homogenous!), most popularly of order 2 or less.

The most useful fact about  the Laplace transform, the one that makes it useful to solve linear ODEs is the following relation between the Laplace transform and the derivative:
$$\mathcal{L}(f')=s\mathcal{L}(f)-f(0)$$

Do note we also need and an initial value of $f$ evaluated at $0$.
Another useful fact about the Laplace transform- since it's defined by the integral:

$$\mathcal{L}(f)=\int_{0}^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$$

It is a linear transformation! (This can be seen by using the linearity of the integral).

These properties of the Laplace transform actually reduce solving an IVP from a differential problem to an algebraic one (It is is a really rich field of research called Operational Calculus!). After applying the transform to both sides of the equation we re-arrange the equation to that we can use the last important property of the Laplace transformation: It is invertible! so after re-arranging we can apply $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ to both sides and thus solve for $f$ .

[Table of the laplace transform for common functions](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx)

Comment: Is the second equation not linearly homogenous?

Comment: Not going to lie, I'm out of my depth with these differential equations but I've got to learn them at a fast pace.

Comment: @MrFlu14 The second equation is a 2nd-order linear nonhomogeneous ODE if you were wondering.

Comment: Thank you @fordjones. what's the difference?

Comment: @MrFlu14 the difference is that the equation is equal to a function ($sin x$), and not $0$. it's of 2$^nd$ order because the highest derivative is the second derivative

Comment: @omer. Can you demonstrate the second one for me? need to compare between yours and Dr. Graubner.

Comment: @MrFlu14 I'm sorry, the calculations turned up pretty bad and unfortunately  I don't have that much time :( I edited my answer with a sketch on how to solve IVPs using the laplace transform for reference, if needed. There are a lot of detailed examples online. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

To solve an inhomogeneous differential equation, we need to add a general solution to a particular solution with known coefficients.

Given an inhomogeneous differential equation, you can convert it to a homogenous equation, solve it, then solve for the coefficients needed to satisfy the original equation.

Using differential operators facilitates this process. In the following $\hat{D}y=\frac{d}{dx}(y)$.

Expressed in this form, th given equation is $(\hat{D}^2+4)y=\sin{(x)}$

We know that $(\hat{D}^2+1)y=0$ has the solution $y=c_1\sin{(x)}+c_2\cos{(x)}$. Turning this around then, we know $(\hat{D}^2+1)(\sin{x})=0$.

So if we multiply both sides of the equation, the we have:

$$(\hat{D}^2+1)(\hat{D}^2+4)y=0.$$

Now that we have a homogenous equation, we can use the usual methods to find that the solution is $y=c_1\sin{x}+c_2\cos{x}+c_3\sin{2x}+c_4\cos{2x}$.

The functions in $2x$ are our general solutions so we don't need to solve for $c_3$ or $c_4$.

If we apply our original differential operator to the trial particular solution, we get that $y''+4y=3c_1\sin{x}+3c_2\cos{x}.$

Our particular solution  is just $\sin{x}$. Solving for coefficients, we get that $c_2=0$ and $c_1=1/3$.

Plugging this in, we get the solution:

$$y=(1/3)\sin{x}+c_3\sin{2x}+c_4\cos{2x}$$.

Answer (score -1):

For your first equation we get
$$y(x)=0$$ or $$y'(x)=0$$
The second one has the solutions
$$y(x)=c_2 \sin (2 x)+c_1 \cos (2 x)+\dfrac{1}{3}\sin x$$

Comment: I got that to. However, I'm not sure if my step-by-steps are misleading. first I did y(x)^2*dy/dx=0, then I separated the variables. Would I be correct?

Comment: Like i have written, consider every factor as a single equation.

Comment: can y(x) be simplified to 1/3sin(x)?

Comment: @MrFlu14 yes it can.

Comment: How did you solve for the first section: c_2sin(2x)+c_1cos(2x)?